# converting allelic form to genotypic form

Tags: r

I am new in R and working on Genomic Selection, and I simulated genomic data.

In my data(markers) file, I want to convert allelic form data (11,12,22) to genotypic

form(0,1,2) i.e columns have 1 1 [1,V4 :V5] convert to 0, columns have 1 2 [3,V4:V5] convert

to 1, columns have 2 2 [1,V14:V15] convert to 2. How can I do this in R?

I have another question, how can I detect columns that have the same numbers?

Sample:

> x1

```
   V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23
1   1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   1
2   1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   2   2   1   1   1   1   1
3   1  2  1  1  1  1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   1   1   1   2
4   1  2  1  1  1  1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   1   1   1   2
5   1  1  1  1  1  1   1   2   1   1   2   2   2   1   1   1   1   2   1   1
6   1  1  1  1  1  1   1   2   1   1   2   2   2   1   1   1   1   2   1   1
7   1  1  1  2  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   2   2   1   1   2   1   2
8   1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   2   2   1   1   1   1   1
9   1  2  1  1  1  1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   1   1   1   2
10  1  2  1  1  1  1   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2   1   1   1   2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 test <- data.frame(apply(x1,1,function(x) sapply(seq(1,length(x),by=2), function(y) paste(x[y],x[y+1],sep="_"))),stringsAsFactors=F)

recode <- function(x) {
  x[x == "1_1"] <- 0
  x[x == "1_2"] <- 1
  x[x == "2_1"] <- 1
  x[x == "2_2"] <- 2
  return(x)
}

test2 <- data.frame(apply(test,1,function(x) recode(as.character(x))))

test2
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1   0  0  0  0  0  2  2  0  0   0
2   0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0   0
3   1  0  0  1  0  0  0  2  0   1
4   1  0  0  1  0  0  0  2  0   1
5   0  0  0  1  0  2  1  0  1   0
6   0  0  0  1  0  2  1  0  1   0
7   0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   1
8   0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0   0
9   1  0  0  1  0  0  0  2  0   1
10  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0   1
```

For the second question (the name is from compare vector elements)

```
compvecele <- function(v) all(sapply(as.list(v[-1]), function(z) {identical(z, v[1])}))
apply(test2,2,function(x) compvecele(x))
```

compvecele gives a vector of TRUE/FALSE where true means all values are identical. To select only columns where there is variation

```
test2[,apply(test2,2,function(x) compvecele(x)) == FALSE]
```

Comment: my dimention file is 4000*10000, how can delete columns after use “compvecele” command?

Comment: for example  


    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1   2  2  0  0  2  0  2  0  0   0
2   1  2  0  0  2  1  1  0  1   0
3   1  2  0  0  2  1  1  0  1   0
4   1  2  0  0  2  1  1  0  1   0
5   2  2  0  1  2  1  2  0  0   1
6   2  2  0  1  2  1  2  0  0   1
7   1  1  0  1  2  2  0  1  1   0
8   1  2  0  0  2  1  1  0  1   0
9   1  2  0  0  2  1  1  0  1   0
10  2  2  0  0  2  0  2  0  0   0
x3, x5 and ... remove and other like this columns until to last column.

Comment: I added the answer to that into my answer. If it does what you want click the tick button.

Answer (score 0):

As for your first question, If I understand what you are asking then this will work assuming your data is stored in `d`:

```
f<-apply(d,1,paste,collapse="")
g<-sapply( seq(1,length(d[1,]),by=2), function(x) substr(f,x,x+1))

g[g=="11"]<-0
g[g=="12"]<-1
g[g=="21"]<-1
g[g=="22"]<-2
```

As for the second question, I'm not sure what you are asking.  Are you looking for identical columns?  It would be helpful if you provided some expected output.

If you want to find columns that only have a single type a value (e.g. only 0, only 1, or only 2) you can get the column number like so:

```
which(sapply(apply(g,2,unique),length) == 1)
```

Comment: ,I means columns that have identical codes(all rows 0 or 1 or 2), remove; for instance column 3 and 5 .

   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1   0  0  0  0  0  2  2  0  0   0
2   0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0   0
3   1  0  0  1  0  0  0  2  0   1
4   1  0  0  1  0  0  0  2  0   1
5   0  0  0  1  0  2  1  0  1   0
6   0  0  0  1  0  2  1  0  1   0
7   0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   1
8   0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0   0
9   1  0  0  1  0  0  0  2  0   1
10  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0   1

Comment: @FrankThank you so much

Comment: I have another problem, in my data sets some columns have a same value except in one or two point, I need to detect and delete this columns, for example in column “1846”:

> x[317:400,1846]
 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
[81] 2 2 1 2

Other row values(1:317 and 400:1200)=2.

How can obtain this?